# access a value in a dif method in same class

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method in a class that calculates loan amounts. the method should return "totalPay" but it is saying that it isn't declared, do you see why?

```
public loan(double anualInterestRate, int numberOfYears, double loanAmount){

    double base = (double) ( loanAmount * (1+anualInterestRate/12));
    double exponent = (double) (numberOfYears * 12);
    double totalPay = (double) Math.pow(base, exponent); 
}
```

and the total payment method that isn't seeing "totalPay" for some reason:

```
/**
 * 
 * @return total payment
 */
public double totalPayment(){
    return totalPay;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring your variables in the constructor making them visible *only in* the constructor. Don't do this. Declare the ones that need class visibility in the class.

i.e.

```
class Loan {
    private double base;
    private double exponent;
    private double totalPay;

    public Loan(double anualInterestRate, int numberOfYears, double loanAmount){

        base = (double) ( loanAmount * (1+anualInterestRate/12));
        xponent = (double) (numberOfYears * 12);
        totalPay = (double) Math.pow(base, exponent); 

        // consider setting other fields with your parameters if they'll be 
        // needed elsewhere
    }
```